# How to disable a specific drive

Tags: windows-services, c#-2.0

I need to disable cdrom and the usb mass storage drivers using c# windows service. i have noticed there is a post [Disable the use of CD drive (VB.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265895/disable-the-use-of-cd-drive-vb-net) but it keeps ejecting the cdrom tray. does anyone know how to disable the cd rom other than using this method.????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have fund a solution

```
#region EjectMedia
        const uint GENERICREAD = 0x80000000;
        const uint OPENEXISTING = 3;
        const uint IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA = 2967560;
        const int INVALID_HANDLE = -1;

        private static IntPtr fileHandle;
        private static uint returnedBytes;

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string fileName,
        uint desiredAccess,
        uint shareMode,
        IntPtr attributes,
        uint creationDisposition,
        uint flagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr templateFile);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr driveHandle);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr driveHandle,
        uint IoControlCode,
        IntPtr lpInBuffer,
        uint inBufferSize,
        IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
        uint outBufferSize,
        ref uint lpBytesReturned,
                 IntPtr lpOverlapped);
        #endregion

private void loop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                if (d.IsReady)
                {
                    if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable || d.DriveType == DriveType.Ram || d.DriveType == DriveType.Unknown) 
                        Eject(@"\\.\" + d.Name.Substring(0, 1) + ":");
                }
            }
}

 public void Eject(string driveLetter)
        {
            try
            {
                fileHandle = CreateFile(driveLetter, GENERICREAD, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPENEXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if ((int)fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE)
                    DeviceIoControl(fileHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref returnedBytes, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            catch
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            }

            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(fileHandle);
                fileHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Vista and above you can use [Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730808%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) settings to disable USB, CD-ROM and other types of removable storage. And you don't even need a service for that. If you cannot do this through group policy infrastructure, there is an option to set registry keys that Group Policy controls. Registry key locations are mentioned in this [Vista forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/57904-gpo-removable-storage-access-bypass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out VolumeManager defined below. It has functionality on locking volumes and disabling CD-ROM eject

```cs
public class VolumeManager
{
    public string DriveLetter { private set; get; }
    public IntPtr hFile { private set; get; }

    public VolumeManager(string driveletter)
    {
        DriveLetter = driveletter;
    }

    public EjectState Eject()
    {
        if (!OpenHandle())
            return EjectState.Failed;

        if (Lock() && Dismount())
        {
            if (PreventRemoval(false) && AutoEject())
            {
                CloseHandle();
                return EjectState.AutoEject;
            }
            else
            {
                CloseHandle();
                return EjectState.RemoveSafely;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle();
            return EjectState.NoLock;
        }
    }

    public bool OpenHandle()
    {
        string filename = "\\\\.\\" + DriveLetter + ":";

        hFile = Win32.CreateFile(filename, Win32.GENERIC_READ | Win32.GENERIC_WRITE,
            Win32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Win32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, Win32.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (hFile.ToInt32() == Win32.INVALID_HANDLE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void CloseHandle()
    {
        Win32.CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    public bool Lock()
    {
        uint bytesReturned = 0;
        int retry = 0;
        while (retry < 20)
        {
            if (Win32.DeviceIoControl(hFile, Win32.FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
                ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                return true;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            retry++;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public bool Dismount()
    {
        uint bytesReturned = 0;
        if (!Win32.DeviceIoControl(hFile, Win32.FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
            ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool PreventRemoval(bool prevent)
    {
        Win32.PREVENT_MEDIA_REMOVAL pmr = new Win32.PREVENT_MEDIA_REMOVAL();
        pmr.PreventMediaRemoval = prevent;
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(pmr));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pmr, ptr, true);

        uint bytesReturned = 0;
        if (!Win32.DeviceIoControl(hFile, Win32.IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL, ptr, Marshal.SizeOf(pmr), IntPtr.Zero, 0,
            ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public bool AutoEject()
    {
        uint bytesReturned = 0;
        if (!Win32.DeviceIoControl(hFile, Win32.IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
            ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public enum EjectState
{
    Failed,
    NoVolume,
    NoLock,
    RemoveSafely,
    AutoEject
}

public class Win32
{
    public const uint FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM = 0x00000009;
    public const uint IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE = 0x0000002d;
    public const uint FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;
    public const uint FILE_READ_ACCESS = 1;
    public const uint METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
    public const uint FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME = ((FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM << 16) | (FILE_ANY_ACCESS << 14) | (6 << 2) | (METHOD_BUFFERED));
    public const uint FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME = ((FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM << 16) | (FILE_ANY_ACCESS << 14) | (8 << 2) | (METHOD_BUFFERED));
    public const uint IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL = ((IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE << 16) | (FILE_READ_ACCESS << 14) | (0x0201 << 2) | (METHOD_BUFFERED));
    public const uint IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA = ((IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE << 16) | (FILE_READ_ACCESS << 14) | (0x0202 << 2) | (METHOD_BUFFERED));

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode, IntPtr lpInBuffer, int nInBufferSize,
        IntPtr lpOutBuffer, uint nOutBufferSize, ref uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    public const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    public const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
    public const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
    public const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    public const int INVALID_HANDLE = -1;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
        uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    public struct PREVENT_MEDIA_REMOVAL
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool PreventMediaRemoval;
    }
}
```

To disable CD-ROM eject:

```cs
string DriveLetter = "G"; // Or whatever letter you have assigned for your CD-ROM
var VolumeManager = new VolumeManager(DriveLetter);
if (VolumeManager.OpenHandle())
{
    if (!VolumeManager.PreventRemoval(true))
    {
        // Failed to disable CD-ROM eject
        VolumeManager.CloseHandle();
    }
}
else
{
    // Failed to access volume
}
```