# VB.NET: Is there a way to disable the DVD-ROM drive through code?

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, dvd

I can enable/disable the DVD-ROM drive through the Device Manager.
Is it possible to do that through the code?
Thank you.

Comment: This is not something that usually needs to be done in code. It is done as part of group policy etc. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: It's just for myself. I want to have a disk in the drive but I do not want Windows to constantly freeze to check on that disk, so I want a handy way to turn on/off the drive with just one click.

Comment: This link have the same problem/solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265895/disable-the-use-of-cd-drive-vb-net